# How do two metal balls of radius $r$ kept at a large distance form a capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

So this is something really new to me. I have learnt of plate capacitors, cylindrical capacitors, single spherical capacitors, etc. but that to, of finite distance between them. Also please explain if the distance is not very large and comparable to their radius how would the capacitance of system differ.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. If you know how plates form a capacitor, what's different for two spheres except that the plates are now curved?

Comment: I mean to say that we can clearly see , the energy is stored between the plates ( in the electric field) but in this arrangement his will we obtain energy density numerically. And also what large separation means here ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how:

[image]

And the expression is (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance#Capacitance_of_simple_systems)):

$$2\pi \varepsilon a\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sinh \left( \ln \left( D+\sqrt{D^2-1}\right) \right) }{\sinh \left( n\ln \left( D+\sqrt{ D^2-1}\right) \right) } $$

Comment: I read the whole thing and understood that the if the separation is large then capacitance of system will be 2πεa. But if the separation is finite say 10a how will we evaluate the problem? I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Well you put the values in the sum, and truncate it up to the level of precision you require.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor can store charge so if both balls were initially uncharged one could move charge from one ball to the other.  Thus the balls now store charge and energy - they can be classed as a capacitor. As the separation between the balls decreases the capacitance of the system increases.